# php switch using strings and foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql

The code below works great for listing each class in rows and I've got it sorted ASC from date and time BUT now I'd like to rearrange it so the classes that occur on Monday appear in order again by start time ASC in column one then continue the loop so classes that occur on Tuesday appear in column two and so on through the week. I'm not sure of the best method or even if I need to rewrite my foreach statements. I've tried switch using strings where each case would equal the days "Monday", "Tuesday", etc.

```
<table>
<tr>
<th width="80">Day</th>
<th width="80">Class</th>
<th width="80">Instructor</th>
<th width="80">Start</th>
<th width="80">End</th>
<th width="80">Studio</th>
</tr>
 <?php
 foreach ($data as $key => $row) 
 {
    $start_date[$key] = $row['Calendar']['start_date'];
    $start_time[$key] = $row['Calendar']['start_time']; 
 }
 array_multisort($start_date, $start_time, $data);

 foreach ($data as $row) {
  <tr>
  <td><?php $row['Calendar']['start_date']; ?></td>
  <td><?php $row['Calendar']['title']; ?></td>
  <td><?php $row['Calendar']['instructor']; ?></td>
  <td><?php $row['Calendar']['start_time']; ?></td>
  <td><?php $row['Calendar']['end_time']; ?></td>
  <td><?php $row['Calendar']['location']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

[image: row list image]

[image: days in columns]

my $data from mysql db when using SQL from Mike B.

```
 array(13) { 
    [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { ["day_index"]=> string(1) "2" } ["calendars"]=> array(4) { ["title"]=> string(19) "Breakaway (Erin K.)" ["start_time"]=> string(8) "12:15:00" ["end_time"]=> string(8) "13:00:00" 

["location"]=> string(28) "Studio 1" } } 
[1]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { ["day_index"]=> string(1) "2" } ["calendars"]=> array(4) { ["title"]=> string(20) "Breakaway (Cindy B.)" ["start_time"]=> string(8) "16:30:00" ["end_time"]=> string(8) "17:15:00" 

["location"]=> string(28) "Studio 1" } } 
[2]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { ["day_index"]=> string(1) "2" } ["calendars"]=> array(4) { ["title"]=> string(20) "Breakaway (Larry N.)" ["start_time"]=> string(8) "18:15:00" ["end_time"]=> string(8) "19:00:00" 

["location"]=> string(28) "Studio 1" } } 
[3]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { ["day_index"]=> string(1) "3" } ["calendars"]=> array(4) { ["title"]=> string(20) "Breakaway (Megan S.)" ["start_time"]=> string(8) "06:45:00" ["end_time"]=> string(8) "07:30:00" 

["location"]=> string(28) "Studio 1" } } 
[4]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { ["day_index"]=> string(1) "3" } ["calendars"]=> array(4) { ["title"]=> string(20) "Breakaway (Larry N.)" ["start_time"]=> string(8) "11:15:00" ["end_time"]=> string(8) "12:00:00" 

["location"]=> string(28) "Studio 1" } } 
[5]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { ["day_index"]=> string(1) "3" } ["calendars"]=> array(4) { ["title"]=> string(19) "Breakaway (Lisa G.)" ["start_time"]=> string(8) "17:30:00" ["end_time"]=> string(8) "18:15:00" 

["location"]=> string(28) "Studio 1" } } 
[6]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { ["day_index"]=> string(1) "4" } ["calendars"]=> array(4) { ["title"]=> string(20) "Breakaway (Megan S.)" ["start_time"]=> string(8) "16:30:00" ["end_time"]=> string(8) "17:15:00" 

["location"]=> string(28) "Studio 1" } } 
[7]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { ["day_index"]=> string(1) "4" } ["calendars"]=> array(4) { ["title"]=> string(19) "Breakaway (Lisa G.)" ["start_time"]=> string(8) "12:15:00" ["end_time"]=> string(8) "13:00:00" 

["location"]=> string(28) "Studio 1" } } 
[8]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { ["day_index"]=> string(1) "5" } ["calendars"]=> array(4) { ["title"]=> string(21) "Breakaway (Lauren M.)" ["start_time"]=> string(8) "06:45:00" ["end_time"]=> string(8) "07:30:00" 

["location"]=> string(28) "Studio 1" } } 
[9]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { ["day_index"]=> string(1) "5" } ["calendars"]=> array(4) { ["title"]=> string(19) "Breakaway (Adam A.)" ["start_time"]=> string(8) "11:15:00" ["end_time"]=> string(8) "12:00:00" 

["location"]=> string(28) "Studio 1" } } 
[10]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { ["day_index"]=> string(1) "5" } ["calendars"]=> array(4) { ["title"]=> string(20) "Breakaway (Cindy B.)" ["start_time"]=> string(8) "17:30:00" ["end_time"]=> string(8) "18:15:00" 

["location"]=> string(28) "Studio 1" } } 
[11]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { ["day_index"]=> string(1) "6" } ["calendars"]=> array(4) { ["title"]=> string(19) "Breakaway (Adam A.)" ["start_time"]=> string(8) "16:30:00" ["end_time"]=> string(8) "17:15:00" 

["location"]=> string(28) "Studio 1" } } 
[12]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { ["day_index"]=> string(1) "7" } ["calendars"]=> array(4) { ["title"]=> string(20) "Breakaway (Rotation)" ["start_time"]=> string(8) "09:35:00" ["end_time"]=> string(8) "10:35:00" 

["location"]=> string(28) "Studio 1" } } }
```

SQL

```
SELECT DAYOFWEEK(start_date) as day_index, title, start_time, end_time, location FROM calendars WHERE calendar_category_id = '3' AND location = 'Studio 1' ORDER BY day_index
```

got it by:

```
$calendar = array(); 
foreach ($data as $row) { 
$calendar[$row[0]['day_index']][] = $row;
}
```

Comment: you don't show the original array is built - if this is coming from a db, then pull out the day-of-week value in the query and use that as a key in the array, so it'll be `$data[$day_of_week][] = $row` in your fetch loop, and now you've automatically got things split by weekday without having to do any extra sorting.

Comment: You have to do this on your `query`. Use it only to display the data. This way you don't have to change it everytime you want to change it's order or structure.

Comment: this is my query 
 $conditions=array("calendar_category_id"=>3, "location"=>"Studio 1");
 
 $data = $this->Calendar->findAll($conditions); 
 
 $this->set('data',$data);

Comment: That is not a SQL query...we need to see your actual SQL query.

Comment: I'm using cakephp but essentialy my query translates to: SELECT * FROM `calendars` WHERE `calendar_category_id` = '3' AND `location` = 'Studio 1'

Comment: sounds like I may need to add a group by start_date in my SQL

Comment: @sloga I doubt you need a `GROUP BY` as this is used in aggregations (`SUM`, `COUNT`, etc.). You just need to possibly do a `DAYOFWEEK(date_field) AS day_index` and `ORDER BY day_index ASC`. When iterating through the result set you just build the two-dimensional array like this `$calendar[$row['day_name']] = $row;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you getting this data from a database?  If so you might want to consider changing up your query to get this different grouping. Perhaps something like this:

```
SELECT DAYOFWEEK(date_field) AS day_index, [... other class fields ...]
FROM table
ORDER BY day_index ASC;
```

Then you could read your data into a two-dimensional array like this:

```
$calendar = array();
while ($row = $db_result->fetch() ) { // or whatever you use to iterate through the result set.
    $calendar[$row['day_index']][] = $row;
}
```

This gives you an array like this:

```
Array(
    '1' => Array(
         0 =>  Array(
             'day_index' =>  '1',
             ... other class fields ...
         ),
         1 =>  Array(
              'day_index' => 1,
             ... other class fields ...
         ),
         ... other class arrays from the result set ...
         ),
    '2' => ... Another numerically indexed array of class arrays for Monday classes ...
    '3' => ... Another numerically indexed array of class arrays for Tuesday classes ...
    ... and so on
)
```

Then it comes down to how you are displaying your data.  I would think that in order to do what you want to do, you might need to go away from the table based layout you have and instead go with something like floated columns.

This might look like this::

```
<?php
$days_of_week = array(
    '1' => 'Sunday',
    '2' => 'Monday',
    // etc.
);
?>
<div style="overflow: auto;">
<?php foreach ($calendar as $day_index => $classes) { ?>
    <div style="width: 150px; margin: 5px; float: left;">
        <div style="margin: auto;"><?php echo $days_of_week[$day_index]; ?></div>
        <?php foreach ($classes as $class) {?>
            <div style="width:150px">
            <!-- class info here -->
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, the data is coming from a mysql db and upon suggestions, I am rewriting my query. I do plan to remove tables and use positioned divs. Thanks for your suggestion, I will try it out.

Comment: I'm not quite understanding the $data[$day_of_week][] =$row by Mark B above or the $calendars = array('Monday' => ([a numerically indexed array of class elements),// by Mike Bryant above.

Comment: @sloga See my updated answer for a more thorough query through display example.

Comment: thanks Mike Brant, the SQL statement is great but I don't understand 2nd part, reading data into array. My array is $data and looks like:  array(13) { 
[0]=> array(1) { ["calendars"]=> array(5) { ["day_index"]=> string(10) "2012-09-10" ["title"]=> string(19) "Breakaway (Erin K.)" ["start_time"]=> string(8) "12:15:00" ["end_time"]=> string(8) "13:00:00" ["location"]=> string(28) "Studio 1" } } 
[1]=> and so on.    I'm not understanding the while statement and the fetch command. Sorry for my lack of experience and I appreciate your assistance.

Comment: @sloga I am not sure what method you are using to iterate over your result set, but using `while()` or other kind of looping structure is a pretty common approach. Some where you are populating your `$data` variable based on your result set.  Al I am giving you is a strategy to get the array in a format that is readily usable for output without needing any further sorting or manipulations.  You can substitute that `while()` in my example with whatever method you use to get a row of data from the database. Bottom lie is that row is represented by `$row` and the array as `$calendar`

Comment: i changed sql to get day_index to be an integer and have while ($row = $data) {$calendar[$row['day_index']][] = $row;} as the second part with no luck.

Comment: @sloga I think you are talking about working with your `$data` array which is populated in some manner from MySQL queries.  I am talking about not using your `$data` structure at all an instead using the approach I indicated to pull populate an array from the query's result set. If you add your DB-related code into your original question, I can give you better direction on what you need to do.

Comment: thanks...the db data is pasted above in the original question. It is the result from your SQL query SELECT DAYOFWEEK...

Comment: @sloga Again, I am no so much concerned about what your current `$data` structure is.  I think that the way you are reading the data into the array from MySQL is making it hard for you to use your data when it is time to display.  I was interested in seeing your actual mysql code so I could offer up a suggestion on how to read the data in the array. I had previously done this, but you did not seem to understand the fact that I used a generic representation for how you loop through the DB result set and can read it into an array that if formatted in a more useful manner.

Comment: OK. Thanks for trying to help. I will keep trying.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22850/discussion-between-mike-brant-and-sloga)

Comment: got it by changing the $calendar = array(); while that you sugested to: $calendar = array(); foreach ($data as $row) { $calendar[$row[0]['day_index']]{} = $row;}

Comment: @sloga Glad you got something to work. Just can be kind of wasteful to read your database result set into `$data` and then re-writing it in different format into `$calendar` rather than reading directly from database into `$calendar` (or `$data` or whatever you want to call it, the variable name is irrelevant).